# presentViewController above container view crashes on ios8

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a main view controller, called `main` . Inside that view controller there is a `container view` .
The container view loads some other view controllers inside itself.
When i want to open the email composer, i do that from the `main` controller, so it should open it above the container view.

On `iOS` smaller than 8 it works great, on `iPad` it works great for any iOS .

**ONLY** in `iOS8` on the iPhone, i get a crash on the line that presents the controller, with *no error message* that i can provide you with :

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
 ....
[self  presentViewController:mailController animated:YES completion:nil]; //****crash here
```

tried also :

```
self.view.window.rootViewController
```

And even tried to add the mail composer as a subview of the contaier :

```
[self.containerView addSubview:mailController.view];
```

Which loads it not good(i see half of it )

Both gives a crash . I could not find any solution to this .

**EDIT :**
Found a solution but i am not sure why it works and i am little bit nervous with it :

```
mailController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

Will make it work .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mailController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

Solves the problem .